# Pandas groupby sum resulting in blanks

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a `pandas` dataframe which looks like this:

| Sub Code | Date | End Date | Monthly Sub Budget | Monthly Sub Spend | Cum Sub Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 3450 | 9-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $70 |
| 345 | 3450 | 10-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $50 |
| 345 | 3450 | 11-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $80 |
| 345 | 3450 | 12-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $50 |
| 345 | 3451 | 12-1-21 | 1-1-21 | $90 | $10 |
| 981 | 9810 | 11-1-20 | 1-1-21 | $80 | $50 |
| 981 | 9810 | 12-1-20 | 1-1-21 | $80 | $30 |

I want to calculate both 'Total Subscription Budget' (the sum of all monthly subscription budgets) and 'Cumulative Subscription Budget' (cumulative sum of monthly subscription budgets) so that the df would look like this:

| Sub Code | Date | End Date | Monthly Sub Budget | Monthly Sub Spend | Cum Sub Spend | Tot Sub Budget | Cum Sub Budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3450 | 9-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $70 | $70 | $400 | $100 |
| 3450 | 10-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $50 | $120 | $400 | $200 |
| 3450 | 11-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $80 | $200 | $400 | $300 |
| 3450 | 12-1-20 | 12-1-20 | $100 | $50 | $250 | $400 | $400 |
| 3451 | 12-1-21 | 1-1-21 | $90 | $10 | $10 | $90 | $100 |
| 9810 | 11-1-20 | 1-1-21 | $80 | $50 | $50 | $160 | $80 |
| 9810 | 12-1-20 | 1-1-21 | $80 | $30 | $80 | $160 | $160 |

Right now I am using the below code which is working for the cumsum but *not* for the sum. The Cumulative Sub Budget column is populated correctly, but the Total Sub Budget column is empty.

```
df['Total Subscription Budget'] = df.groupby('Sub Code')['Monthly Sub Budget'].sum()  
df['Cumulative Subscription Budget'] = df.groupby('Sub Code')['Monthly Sub Budget'].cumsum()
```

I have found plenty of cases where sum worked and cumsum didn't but haven't seen anyone else have this problem. What should I do to make the `.sum()` work?

Comment: Check for missing values in your grouby by values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df['Total Subscription Budget'] = df.groupby('Sub Code')['Monthly Sub Budget'].transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a roundabout approach:

```py
#Sum does not work because it doesn't repeat the value for each row.
x = df.groupby('Sub Code')['Monthly Sub Budget'].sum()
x.rename('Total Subscription Budget', inplace=True)
```

```py
#I think what we can do is join this output to the main table like this
pd.merge(df, x, on='Sub Code')
```